# Logstash grok doesn't match for specific field

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok

I have tab separated string and I want to extract each fields using grok plugin.
The tab separated string is like

> http://www.allaboutpc.co.kr 2016110913  d6123c6caa12f08852c82b876bdd3ceceb166d5e    0   0   1   0   /Event/QuizChoice.asp?IdxEvent=3141

I would like to get each fields as **url**, **datetime**, **hashvalue**, **count1**, **count2**, **count3**, **count4**, **path**.

I used **%{DATA:hashvalue}** for 3rd field to extract **hashvalue** but logstash didn't print hashvalue

Here is my conf file

```
input {
    stdin { }
    file {
        path => "/Users/Projects/webmastermrinput/20161021/17/*"
        codec => plain
    }
}
filter {
    # tab to space 
    mutate {
       gsub => ["message", "\t", " "]
    }
    grok {
        match => {
            'message' => "%{DATA:url} %{NUMBER:datetime2} %{DATA:hashvalue} %    {NUMBER:count1} %{NUMBER:count2} %{NUMBER:count3} %{NUMBER:count4} %      {URIPATHPARAM:path}'
        }
    }
}
output {
    stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

Logstash output for input : "http://www.allaboutpc.co.kr 2016110913  d6123c6caa12f08852c82b876bdd3ceceb166d5e    0   0   1   0   /Event/QuizChoice.asp?IdxEvent=3141"

```
{
    "@timestamp" => 2016-11-11T02:26:01.828Z,
    "@version" => "1",
    "host" => "MacBook-Air-10.local",
    "datetime" => "2016110913",
    "message" => "http://www.allaboutpc.co.kr 2016110913  d6123c6caa12f08852c82b876bdd3ceceb166d5e    0   0   1   0   /Event/QuizChoice.asp?IdxEvent=3141",
    "url" => "http://www.allaboutpc.co.kr"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your grok works perfectly well, you just need to remove the spaces between `%`and `{` in `%    {NUMBER:count1}` and `%      {URIPATHPARAM:path}`

```
'message' => "%{DATA:url} %{NUMBER:datetime2} %{DATA:hashvalue} %    {NUMBER:count1} %{NUMBER:count2} %{NUMBER:count3} %{NUMBER:count4} %      {URIPATHPARAM:path}'
                                                                  ^                                                                         ^
                                                                  |                                                                         |
                                                                 here                                                                    and here
```